# Barplot of observations by color

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataframe with 50965 lines and 4 columns as follows:

```
hap1_a hap2_a hap1_b hap2_b
EUR EUR EUR EUR
EUR EUR AFR EUR
EUR EUR AFR EUR
AFR EUR AFR NAM
AFR EUR NAM NAM
NAM EUR NAM NAM
```

Each observation can be either AFR, EUR or NAM.
What I would like is to plot a stacked barplot (Barchart) and color the observations based on blue for EUR, red for AFR and green for NAM so I can do a direct comparison by color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = F)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = 'hap1_a hap2_a hap1_b hap2_b
EUR EUR EUR EUR
EUR EUR AFR EUR
EUR EUR AFR EUR
AFR EUR AFR NAM
AFR EUR NAM NAM
NAM EUR NAM NAM')

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = name, y = ..count.., fill = value)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

---

For requirement stated in comments

```r
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = F)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = 'hap1_a hap2_a hap1_b hap2_b
EUR EUR EUR EUR
EUR EUR AFR EUR
EUR EUR AFR EUR
AFR EUR AFR NAM
AFR EUR NAM NAM
NAM EUR NAM NAM')

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  mutate(value = as.factor(match(value, unique(value)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = ..count.., fill = value)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'red', 'green'), labels = c('EUR', 'AFR', 'NAM'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal, I see that that the colors are not in order of appearance (observation). For example, I would expect on the firs column hap1_a, to be EUR, EUR, EUR, AFR, AFR, NAM > Blue, Blue, Blue, Red, Red, Green

I think they are sorted on you example right? I need it to be the exact same order as appearance...

Comment: Basically need to plot the data frame the way it is in a barplot, but changing the name to specific colors.

Comment: @guidebortoli, Glad to have been of help. :)